# django how to download a file from the internet

Tags: python, django

I want to have a user input a file URL and then have my django app download the file from the internet.

My first instinct was to call wget inside my django app, but then I thought there may be another way to get this done. I couldn't find anything when I searched. Is there a more django way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508715/python-download-images-with-alernating-variables/38510385#38510385

Comment: You should be _very_ careful with downloading whatever the user specifies. The `REQUESTS` library can handle it: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not really dependent on Django for this.
I happen to like using `requests` library.

Here is an example:

```
    import requests

    def download(url, path, chunk=2048):
        req = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if req.status_code == 200:
            with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk):
                    f.write(chunk)
                f.close()
            return path
        raise Exception('Given url is return status code:{}'.format(req.status_code))
```

Place this is a file and import into your module whenever you need it.

Of course this is very minimal but this will get you started.

Comment: cool, just wanted to know if I should reach into a plain python library or if there was a djangified way to do it

Comment: in this, it will save the file in local but I don't want to save the file locally it should be available for download directly to a user

Answer (score 1):

You can use urlopen from urllib2 like in this example:

```
import urllib2
pdf_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/files/some_file.pdf")
with open('test.pdf','wb') as output:
    output.write(pdf_file.read())
```

For more information, read the [urllib2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen).